# Android TV PlaybackControlsRow

Tags: android

So building a new app specifically for the Android TV interface (lollipop leanback) and I'm using the PlaybackOverlayFragment that is provided by the framework which has a PlaybackControlsRow with all the usual controls on it.

The problem is, the default behavior is for the user to have to click the "Play" button to start the video and I want it to start automatically.  That part is easy and I have it working but then the Play/Pause icons on the provided control are out of sync (showing play when should be pause) because the item was started outside of the events of clicking on that control.

Documentation is sparse on these framework elements and examining the class I can't find any public method that would allow me to put this control in the proper "mode" or tell it to display the play or pause icon myself.

Anyone with experience with these yet that would know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to change the state of the button, even after adding your Actions to the Adapter, you'll need to notify the changes to the adapter that has your Action.

```
mPlayPauseAction.nextIndex(); // next index, if it was pause, it'll be play
notifyChanged(mPlayPauseAction);

// where notifyChanged(Action action) is:
private void notifyChanged(Action action) {
    ArrayObjectAdapter adapter = mPrimaryActionsAdapter; // reference to your adapter
    if (adapter.indexOf(action) >= 0) {
        adapter.notifyArrayItemRangeChanged(adapter.indexOf(action), 1);
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I partially answered my own question.

If I know before the PlaybackControlsRow is created that I want to set it to the pause state (actually, playing state but showing pause button) then if I call setIndex(PlaypauseAction.PAUSE) on the PlayPauseAction before adding it to the controlsrow then it works.

It doesn't appear that I can modify it myself after adding it but that may be something else I'm doing wrong.